# Get Application/User name causing "Select permission was denied on the object"

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are receiving lots of alerts/notification of error "SELECT permission was denied on the object 'xyz', database 'someDB', schema 'dbo' (so we know the object, database name & schema name)
There are hundreds of applications that connect to that database in question.

Question: we are unable to determine which Application is causing this. Not allowed to run "Trace" or "Extended Events" on the production database.  Any ideas on how to find out the application name along with the user-name that is causing this (attempting to run the SELECT)?

TIA.

P.S.

- We're using SQL Server 2019.
- There is nothing in the SQL Error-logs for this error.
- Once we have the Application-name/user-name we can
  rectify the permission issue (we know how to resolve the permission
  issue, online-searches only show how to resolve this permission
  issue - which is not useful), it's the offending user/application
  that we need to identify.

Comment: *"Not allowed to run "Trace" or "Extended Events" on the production database."* why not? An extended event is very likely what you want and need here.

Comment: @Larnu,  thanks, we are only allowed to run XE/Trace briefly (not allowed to leave them running - due to performance impact).  We're getting this error/alert at random times of the day, so don't really know when to run the XE (like I said can't leave them running).

Comment: Extended Events, compared to traces, have a (*much*) smaller impact on performance, if I am honest. Why not set up an XE, and as well as having it monitoring for the particular problem, monitor how much the performance is impacted. With the right XE, minimised to the specific event(s) you need, you might find that the impact is (*far*) lower than think it is.

Comment: Process of elimination. Enable trace/xe for half of the connections. Does your issue resolve? Cut that in half. Issue is back, try the other half. etc. etc. Curious that you're getting that error message but no context of where it is originating from however. How do you get the alert/error? Logging? Email?

Comment: From experience, users are terrible at reporting errors, @ClearlyClueless . I **literally** *just* got told about a problem on a system 5 minutes ago, and when I asked "How long has the undesired behaviour been occurring?" the answer I got was "years". it only became a "problem" because a manager informed us that the report was "broken" (in actuality, there was a validation error on the user application, and so the staff, instead of raising a ticket, simply weren't entering the needed information and so there was no data to report on /sigh).

Comment: I'm all too familiar. I was just curious if it was being originated from the application itself and if so what sort of context came over with it.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments,  @ ClearlyClueless,  we have a 3rd party application (SQL Sentry) that is firing these alerts (without much/detailed context info).  
@Larnu,  I agree we may need to eventually go on the XE route, but I was just curious if there was another way to detect Application/User.

Comment: if SQL Sentry manages, then it probably reads it from somewhere, are you sure you don't have trace running? select * from sys.traces . I think you can run a trace for a few hours and make sure it logs errors as written here: https://www.melodiouscode.net/tracing-sql-permission-denied-errors You can set filter on the database that you get errors about. Hopefully it will lead to some good info

Comment: "we are only allowed to run XE/Trace briefly" - by whom? My recommendation would be to propose a targeted XE for your problem with this individual/group, start the XE, and have them point out the performance impact. At least one of you or them is going to learn something about the veracity of their claim in re: "XE sessions cause performance problems".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for commenting and suggesting to run XE/Trace (which I don't deny), however, we found a solution to find the relevant information without having to use/rely on the XE/trace.

Essentially, to find out the user-name & their other details (for whom permission denied error is being notified) RDP into the database server and look into the Windows' **Event Logs** -> expand the "Windows Logs" and look at the error or information (matching the time when alert/notification was sent), here you will see the user-name under "User" field.

[image]

Hope this helps others (in similar situation).